# How to fix if one press one operator and then another operator in Calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a calculator for FreeCodeCamp challenge. My code is almost done except for several problems. One of the problems is the repeating operators. For example, if someone press "5+" then changed his mind, pressing the "-" instead, the result should be "5-" instead.

Here is my original code from my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MEQvqv):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = "0";
  var subMath = "0";
  var finalset = "";
  var subMatharray = [];
  var equaltrue = false;
  update();
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    console.log("buttonpress: " + keyitem);
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case ".":
        addDecimal(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual(keyitem);
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = "0";
     subMath = "0";
     subMatharray = [];
    if(mainMath.length > 0){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "4em");
    }
    console.log("clearMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("clearSub: " + subMath);
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen() {
     mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
    finalset = mainMath;
    console.log("plusminusMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("plusminusFinal: " + finalset);
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (mainMath == "0"){
      mainMath = keyitem/*mainMath.replace("0", keyitem);*/
      finalset = mainMath;
      return;
      console.log("addedMainZero: " + mainMath);
      console.log("addedFinalZero: " + finalset);
    }
    if (equaltrue == true){
      mainMath = keyitem;
      subMath = "0";
      subMatharray = [];
      console.log("addNumberEqualmain: " + mainMath);
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
    finalset = mainMath;
    
    console.log("addedMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("addedFinalset: " + finalset);
    console.log("addedarray: " + subMatharray);
    
    if(mainMath.length > 8){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "1.5em");
    }
    
  };
  
  function addOperator(keyitem){
    if (equaltrue == true){
      subMatharray = [];
      console.log("addOpEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    }
    subMatharray.push(mainMath,keyitem);
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    mainMath = "0";
    console.log("addOpSub: " + subMath);
    console.log("addOpMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("addOpMainarray: " + subMatharray);
    console.log("equaltrueTest: " + equaltrue);
  };
  
  function addDecimal(keyitem){
    if (mainMath.indexOf(keyitem) === -1){
      if(mainMath == "0") {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        return;
      }
    } else {
        return;
      }
    addNumber(keyitem);
  };
  
  function solveEqual(keyitem) {
    mainMath = eval(subMath+mainMath);
    console.log("solveEqualresult: " + mainMath);
    subMatharray.push(finalset);
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    console.log("solveEqualhistory: " + subMath);
    console.log("solveEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    var finalresult = mainMath.toString();
    if(finalresult.length > 8){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "1.5em");
    }
    equaltrue = true;
  };
  
  function update(){
  $("#answer").html(mainMath);
  $("#history").html(subMath);
};
  
});

/*Problems
2. I need to work on percentage button soon...
3. fix the problem if someone click an operator more than one.
*/
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 75px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 150px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer">0</p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to attempt to edit the code but it's not working very well. Here is my attempt at this area in `function addOperator()`.

```
function addOperator(keyitem){
    var opkeyitem = "";
    oppArray.push(keyitem);
    console.log("addoppArray: " + oppArray);
    if (oppArray.length > 1){
            oppArray.shift();  
      opkeyitem = oppArray.toString();
      subMatharray[1] = opkeyitem;
      subMath = subMatharray.join("");
      oppArray = [];
      console.log("addoppArrayShift: " + oppArray);
      console.log("addoppSubShift: " + subMatharray);
     } else if(oppArray.length == 1) {
      opkeyitem = oppArray.toString();
       if (equaltrue == true){
      subMatharray = [];
      console.log("addOpEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    }
    subMatharray.push(mainMath,opkeyitem);
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    mainMath = "0";
    oppArray = [];
    }   
  };
```

My idea was to store the operators pressed in an array. If it's more than one operator, then the array should knock off the first element and use the last element and add/replace it to the history area.

How do you suggest I go about solving this problem?

Comment: The problem is the logic in your `addOperator` function. It inserts a `"0"`. Also, all of your variables are global that is bad.

Comment: Yes, that was in my original code. Didn't you check out my attempt?

Comment: If You want to persistently store last operator You might want to modify addOperator function `if (!this.oppArray) this.oppArray = []; this.oppArray.push(keyitem);` replacing oppArray inside with `this.oppArray` calls.

Comment: @JustMe Your comment is a bit confusing. Could you write it out in proper code either here in a post or in a private conversation, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember what was the last pressed button and change the logic of `addOperator` function accordingly. If the last pressed button was operator and someone pressed operator again, it should first pop the original one out of the array, where you are saving pressed buttons and then push the new one into it.

A simple boolean variable `lastPressedIsOperator` could do all the job or create a more general `lastPressedType` string variable and change it to `'operator'`/`'number'`/etc. accordingly to last pressed button. Then in `addOperator` first check what is in that variable and act accordingly as I described above.

Comment: Could you please write it out in a code? I did try to write code similar to what you suggested but it didn't work out...

Comment: you need to do something like the code at the end of this comment if the last pressed is operator and the currently pressed is also operator to delete the last operator from your "buffers" and add the new one `subMatharray.pop();  subMath = subMath.slice(0,-1); subMatharray.push(keyitem);`